# Can I have 2 actions with the same name, 1 for GET and 1 for POST?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want my login page to be at

```
/user/login
```

and have it post to the same path:

```
/user/login
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Just check the action in your method.